# Galaxy Nexus sometimes loses home Wi-Fi network (Linksys E900)

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I have Gnex stock 4.3, rooted. Sometimes it loses connection to home Wi-Fi, I take it and it has no Wi-Fi icon, and if I go to the settings it will say "Connecting..." and have one signal bar, it won't ever connect till I restart the router. I have Linksys E900 with WPA2, and "keep wifi during sleep - always" and "minimize wifi battery usage - on" in the phone. That never happened when I had AT&T u-verse router.

Comment: I know next to nothing about routers, so someone will help with that when they see this. Have you got the correct baseband and radio for your current Jelly Bean ROM? The wrong bootloader, radio or baseband can cause WiFi issues. Have you tried WiFi fixer or similar apps to see if they help with the issue? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wahtod.wififixer&hl=en_GB